# Am facing Access denied issue in reading csv data from S3 in Lambda using Node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am working with a scenario, whenever CSV file gets pushed into AWS s3, through cloudtrail and event bridge lambda get triggered. In that lambda, I am trying to read that CSV data and need to convert into JSON. I am able to read data from s3, but unable to parse it. Tried many ways. Please some help me what am missing here

App.js

```
const bucket= 'patterns-s3-eventbridge-src-bucket-new';//event['detail'].requestParameters.bucketName,
const objectkey= 'test.csv'
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey };
const results = [];

exports.handler = function (event, ctx, callback) {
    try {
        const file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        file
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function (data) {
                results.push(data); // --> here
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log(results);
                callback(null, results);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(Error(err));
    }

};
```

temp.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: S3-to-EventBridge Integration 1 - Simple Invoke

Parameters:
  SourceBucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: patterns-s3-eventbridge-src-bucket-new

  LoggingBucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: patterns-s3-eventbridge-ct-logs-new

Resources:
  # S3 Bucket - A source bucket and a logging bucket
  SourceBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref SourceBucketName

  LoggingBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref LoggingBucketName

  # Bucket policy enables CloudTrail to write to the logging bucket
  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref LoggingBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: AWSCloudTrailAclCheck
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
            Action: s3:GetBucketAcl
            Resource: !GetAtt LoggingBucket.Arn
          - Sid: AWSCloudTrailWrite
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
            Action: s3:PutObject
            Resource: !Sub ${LoggingBucket.Arn}/AWSLogs/${AWS::AccountId}/*
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                s3:x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control

  # The CloudTrail trail - uses the LoggingBucketName as the trail name
  myTrail:
    Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
    DependsOn: BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      TrailName: !Ref LoggingBucketName
      S3BucketName: !Ref LoggingBucket
      IsLogging: true
      IsMultiRegionTrail: false
      EventSelectors:
        - IncludeManagementEvents: false
          DataResources:
            - Type: AWS::S3::Object
              Values:
                - !Sub ${SourceBucket.Arn}/
      IncludeGlobalServiceEvents: false

  ### This section configures the consuming Lambda function ###

  # Lambda function
  EventConsumerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: eventConsumer/
      Handler: app.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x

  # EventBridge rule - invokes EventConsumerFunction 
  EventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: EventRule
      State: ENABLED
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail:
          eventName:
            - PutObject
          requestParameters:
            bucketName:
              - !Ref SourceBucket
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt EventConsumerFunction.Arn
          Id: EventConsumerFunctionTarget

  PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref EventConsumerFunction
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt EventRule.Arn
```

Getting Error like this

```
2022-11-20T11:10:04.221Z    3393a03e-c793-42a1-b4f2-eaee4365e6a8    ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "AccessDenied",
    "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "region": null,
    "time": "2022-11-20T11:10:04.220Z",
    "requestId": "G9BZX6PSC8XZ5NVC",
    "extendedRequestId": "Wpet8ECVvRWEJu25NV8DYM7kYlKgGFCxhuCwg9tojnTd24LfFtBCzSdO953f3HBwmBWaVEDk4WQ=",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 72.92149207351702,
    "stack": [
        "AccessDenied: Access Denied",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:711:35)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: No, you are not "able to read it". You get a 403 error, which typically means, that the authorized user -- although it might be valid -- is not allowed to access that particular object.

Comment: Thanks, @derpirscher for the reply. Is there any other way to read csv in lamda